# Bootstrap tour not working this._options.storage.getItem

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-tour

I had my Bootstrap tour working correctly but then I did some work and can not figure out where I messed up. I can't post the git repo since it is private.
So my error is that the code is to run when you first go to a page the first time. The error I am getting inside my Chrome console is:

```
bootstrap-tour.min.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: this._options.storage.getItem is not a function
    at o._getState (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22)
    at o.ended (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22)
    at o.init (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22)
    at main.js:207
    at main.js:212
```

My code for the initial page load after login

```
if(location.href == 'https://example.com/dashboard'){
    (function(){

        var tour = new Tour({
            storage : true,
             steps: [
            {
              element: ".tour-step.tour-step-one",
              placement: "top",
              title: "Welcome to Phantom AM!",
              content: "This tour will guide you through some of the features we'd like to point out.",
            },
            {
              element: ".tour-step.tour-step-two",
              placement: "bottom",
              title: "Quick Tracker",
              content: "These four boxes show a quick look at what you have tracked so far.",
            },
            {
              element: ".tour-step.tour-step-three",
              placement: "right",
              title: "Add a manufacturer",
              content: "Start by adding a manufacturer.",

            },
            {
              element: ".tour-step.tour-step-four",
              title: "Title of my step",
              content: "Content of my step",
              path: "/dashboard/it/manufacturer/new"
            }
        ]
        });

        // Initialize the tour
        tour.init(); **// error line**

        // Start the tour
        tour.start();

    }()); **// error line**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
storage: true
```

to

```
storage: window.localStorage
```

The storage system you want to use. Could be the objects window.localStorage, window.sessionStorage or your own object.
You can set this option as false to disable storage persistence (the tour starts from beginning every time the page is loaded).

You can refer to the documentation of Bootstrap tour pabe

http://bootstraptour.com/api/